# Show Windows security window when calling shortcut from command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, shortcut

I have a shortcut on the desktop which links to a folder on a server. So when I double click it, a security window pops up asking me for my username and password as shown below

[image]

Now I am trying to call the shortcut from a bat file but the problem is that the security window doesn't appear and in the command line it says "Access Denied" although the bat file is run as administrator. I have to say that it works on some computers and others not but I don't know why? Any advice why it works normally from the desktop but not from the bat file?

Here is the bat file:

```
start "" "C:\Users\userA\Desktop\My-Server-folder.lnk"
```

Comment: Post the script.

Comment: @jwdonahue Question updated

Comment: You can't (or at least shouldn't) call shortcuts from batch. What is the shortcut actually a link to? Use that instead.

Comment: @SomethingDark The shortcut is for a folder on a server which requires a login with username and password, that’s why the windows security window shows up. That’s why I want it appearing when calling it from batch.

Comment: Try editing the environment variable called "PATHEXT".  Add .LNK to it.  Then try calling it without the ".lnk" in the filename.  It might help you get around this.  Understand that this makes the system less secure if you aren't careful.